# Add Google Maps suggested route for driving in my own app

Tags: android

I have the address of two locations.

How can I add Google Maps suggested route function for driving in my own android app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google's [Direction Services API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: It is for web. How can I apply to Android?